# Python Smartcrop how to save the cropped image?

Tags: python

I have pip3 install smartcrop. I can run it by using command console, it can return me a image that is contain the main object. Then I try to copy the sample code from github's smartcrop page. At last the python program will return the object result that should be Image from Pillow. I print it out and return a JSON. But I really don't know how to save it as image. How to save it by python coding?  (of course I can use os.system() to execute command console... so please don't suggest me like that XD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Image library instead.

Firstly install it using pip :

```
pip install Image
```

Sample snippet :

```
import Image

image=Image.open('test.png')

imageBox = image.getbbox()
cropped=image.crop(imageBox)
cropped.save('test_cropped.png')
```

Comment: After pip3 install Image, I import Image still return no module named Image. From PIL import Image, that will return the image with full picture without cropping.